# "Initialize language runtime" with error message containing JS file content only

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, passenger, yarnpkg, webpacker

I have a Rails 6 application with Webpacker on a virtual host using Plesk. Node.js packages have been successfully installed with yarn.

When calling the website, Phusion Passenger fails with:

[image]

And the Stdout/stderr output of the failing subprocess just prints the first 65412 characters of my public/packs/js/application-ad2c73bce874600d5502.js file, without any more error details... What does that mean, and how can I get it running?

**Passenger Core:**

PID
27769

Backtrace

```
     in 'bool Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::checkCurrentState()' (Perform.h:238)
     in 'void Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::waitUntilSpawningFinished(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&)' (Perform.h:213)
     in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakePerform::execute()' (Perform.h:1752)
     in 'Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::internalSpawn(const AppPoolOptions&, Passenger::SpawningKit::Config&, Passenger::SpawningKit::HandshakeSession&, const Passenger::Json::Value&, Passenger::SpawningKit::JourneyStep&)' (DirectSpawner.h:211)
     in 'virtual Passenger::SpawningKit::Result Passenger::SpawningKit::DirectSpawner::spawn(const AppPoolOptions&)' (DirectSpawner.h:261)
     in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (SpawningAndRestarting.cpp:95)
```

User and group

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Ulimits

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39266
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39266
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Environment variables

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify
LANG=C
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.8
```

**Subprocess:**

PID
3850

Stdout and stderr output

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/myapp/public/packs/js/application-ad2c73bce874600d5502.js:2
[The first 65412 characters of the file content]
```

User and group

```
uid=10000(mthcgidu) gid=1003(psacln) groups=1003(psacln)
```

Ulimits

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 39266
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 39266
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Environment variables

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
NOTIFY_SOCKET=/run/systemd/notify
LANG=C
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD=true
SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.9 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.8
IN_PASSENGER=1
PASSENGER_SPAWN_WORK_DIR=/tmp/passenger.spawn.XXXXoUtv1L
PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
NODE_PATH=/usr/share/passenger/node
RAILS_ENV=development
RACK_ENV=development
WSGI_ENV=development
NODE_ENV=development
PASSENGER_APP_ENV=development
USER=mthcgidu
LOGNAME=mthcgidu
SHELL=/usr/local/psa/bin/chrootsh
HOME=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com
PWD=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/myapp
GEOIP_ADDR=[...]
HTTPS=on
PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0
PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0
PERL5LIB=/usr/share/awstats/lib:/usr/share/awstats/plugins
UNIQUE_ID=YVCbtpjnrt9WLCv4IWd-gAAAAMM
WEBPACKER_NODE_MODULES_BIN_PATH=/httpdocs/myapp/node_modules/.bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JS file was minified, thus containing a single line only. I downloaded the file, run some code formating, and uploaded the resulting content with ~25000 lines by replacing the original minified content. Then I could see the line responsible for the error, and also error message and backtrace.